# Linux CLI - How to get substring from JSON jq + grep?

Tags: json, bash, grep, jq, pathname

I need to pull a substring from JSON.  In the JSON doc below, I need the end of the value of `jq '.[].networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id'`  In other words, I need just `A10NICvw4konls2vfbw-data` to pass to another command.  I can't seem to figure out how to pull a substring using grep.  I've seem regex examples out there but haven't been successful with them.

```
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/blah/resourceGroups/IPv6v2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/A10VNAvw4konls2vfbw",
    "instanceView": null,
    "licenseType": null,
    "location": "centralus",
    "name": "A10VNAvw4konls2vfbw",
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "/subscriptions/blah/resourceGroups/IPv6v2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/A10NICvw4konls2vfbw-data",
          "resourceGroup": "IPv6v2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, `sub(".*/";"")` will do the trick as * is greedy:

```
.[].networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id | sub(".*/";"")
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
jq -r '.[]|.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id | split("/") | last'
```

The `-r` tells JQ to print the output in "raw" form - in this case, that means no double-quotes around the string value.

As for the `jq` expression, after you access the `id` you want, piping it (still inside `jq`) through `split("/")` turns it into an array of the parts between slashes. Piping that through the `last` function (thanks, @Thor) returns just the last element of the array.

Comment: Or `.[] | .networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id | split("/") | last`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with `grep` here is one way:

```
jq -r '.[].networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id' | grep -o '[^/]*$'
```

Output:

```
A10NICvw4konls2vfbw-data
```